# phpactiverecord joins with limit

Tags: join, phpactiverecord

What's the correct way of adding a limit to an activerecord query which includes join statements? I've already got an activerecord join statement which converts to the correct SQL

```
static $belongs_to = array(
array('job_request')
);

$requests = $this->all(array(
    'joins' => array('job_request'),
    'conditions' =>  array('DATE(job_date) >= ? AND DATE(job_date) <= ? AND'
                . ' user_id = ?', $start_date, $end_date, $userid))
);
```

This converts to SQL as

```
SELECT `job_applications`.* FROM `job_applications` INNER JOIN `job_requests`  
ON(`job_applications`.job_request_id = `job_requests`.id) WHERE 
DATE(job_date) >= '2013-01-28' AND DATE(job_date) <= '2013-03-04' 
AND user_id = '1'
```

but if I add a limit, the join is removed from the SQL query

```
$requests = $this->all(array(
    'joins' => array('job_request'),
    'conditions' =>  array('DATE(job_date) >= ? AND DATE(job_date) <= ? AND'
                . ' user_id = ?', $start_date, $end_date, $userid)),
             array('limit' => 200, 'offset' => 0)
```

);

Generates

```
SELECT * FROM `job_applications` LIMIT 0,999999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limit and offset belong within the first array.

```
array('conditions'=>'...',
      'joins'=>'...',
      'limit'=>5',
      'offset'=>5
);
```

Your array looks like

```
 array('conditions'=>'...',
      'joins'=>'...'),
      array('limit'=>5','offset'=>5)
);
```